# Magento CE 1.9.0.1 Array to string conversion Zend DB Adapter Pdo Abstract.php

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, zend-framework, array

I get this Error in Magento... `/var/log/system.log` since 
a few weeks, - CE 1.9.0.1 with Firegento, german localisation Mage_Setup

```
  ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in
...\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 74
```

I don´t know what does it mean. The code

```
protected function _dsn()
{   // baseline of DSN parts
    $dsn = $this->_config;

    // don't pass the username, password, charset, 
            // persistent and driver_options in the DSN
    unset($dsn['username']);
    unset($dsn['password']);
    unset($dsn['options']);
    unset($dsn['charset']);
    unset($dsn['persistent']);
    unset($dsn['driver_options']);

    // use all remaining parts in the DSN
    foreach ($dsn as $key => $val) 
            {
        $dsn[$key] = "$key=$val";  /* this is line 74 */
    }
    return $this->_pdoType . ':' . implode(';', $dsn);
}
```

What do I have to do.
Many Thanks for help, I didn´t find any help and answers in the web, in magento forums.

Petra Klapproth
(localhost for testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be chances of `$val` to be an array for any index. change the error line

```
$dsn[$key] = "$key=$val";  /* this is line 74 */
```

to

```
if(is_array($val)){$val = implode(',',$val);}
$dsn[$key] = $key."=".$val;  /* this is line 74 */
```

Comment: @Mrs_PetraByte please accept by clicking the tick so it turns to green and vote the answer.